# Project conflicts with classes from two cocoa pods having the same name - what now?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have imported SwiftyStoreKit as well as FirebaseDatabase. Unfortunately, both pods use a class named "TransactionResult", so I can't use either. 
I tried finding the Firebase source files, which is actually not a good idea, but I could not find any possibility to alter the name of their TransactionResult class. The one in SwiftyStoreKit apparently derives from the Apple's StoreKit library, so I doubt that I will be able to rename that either. What can I do in that case? Every time I use Firebase TransactionResult, I receive an "TransactionResult is ambiguous" error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can specify which `TransactionResult` class you are using by prefixing it with the module name, e.g. `SwiftyStoreKit.TransactionResult` and `FirebaseDatabase.TransactionResult`.

(the prefix should be whatever the name of the module is when you import it):

```swift
import ModuleOne
import ModuleTwo

let v1 = Swift.ClassName
let v2 = ModuleOne.ClassName
let v3 = ModuleTwo.ClassName
```

Hope this helps!